# maintaining a session using struts2 and hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, session, struts2

I need to know how to maintain a session in Struts 2 I have one form and two buttons like add and update...if you add more time same form the data will stored to session and I deleted one form detail in session not database and finally submit the form and all form details will stored to database ...can anyone know  how to do it please help me to solve this
my code is:

```
    public class LogingEx extends ActionSupport implements SessionAware{    

    private int id;

    private String stuname,country;
    private int stumarks,stuage;
    private static final String HELLO_COUNT = "helloCount";
    private Map userSession;;

    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name = "mygen1", strategy = "increment")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "mygen1")
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getStuname() {
        return stuname;
    }
    public void setStuname(String stuname) {
        this.stuname = stuname;
    }

    public int getStuage() {
        return stuage;
    }
    public void setStuage(int stuage) {
        this.stuage = stuage;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }
    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    public int getStumarks() {
        return stumarks;
    }
    public void setStumarks(int stumarks) {
        this.stumarks = stumarks;
    }


    public String execute() throws IOException
    {   

        userSession.put("a",stuname);
        userSession.put("b", stuage);
        userSession.put("c",stumarks);
        userSession.put("d",country);

        Database.saveData(this);
        return SUCCESS;
    }
     public void setSession(Map session) {
         userSession = session ;
        }  
}
```

DATABASE:

```
public class Database {
    public static int saveData(LogingEx e){
    SessionFactory sf=new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    Session session=sf.openSession();
    Transaction tran=session.beginTransaction();

    int i=(Integer)session.save(e);
    tran.commit();
    session.close();
    return i;

}
}
```

STRUTS :

```
 <struts>
        <package name="default" extends="struts-default">
             <action name="verify" class="org.LogingEx">
                <result name="success">/index.jsp</result>           
            </action>
        </package>
    </struts>
```

JSP:

```
    <s:form action="verify">

        <s:textfield name="stuname" label="Enter Username" /><br>
        <s:textfield name="stuage" label="Enter Age" /><br>
        <s:textfield name="stumarks" label="Enter Marks" /><br>
        <s:textfield name="country" label="Enter Country" /><br>
        <s:submit value="Click" id="submit" align="center" /> 
    </s:form>

    Name:<s:property value="#session.a" /><br>
    Age:<s:property value="#session.b" /> <br>
    Marks:<s:property value="#session.c" /><br>
    Country:<s:property value="#session.d" />
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I'm not clear on the question: are you asking how to put data in the session, or how to use Hibernate?

Comment: maintaining session: i have one form ..form data will added to session..second time i added same form data into session and added many times finally all data will stored to database...u have any idea?

Comment: I still don't understand: do you know how to access the session in S2? It's documented.

Comment: ya i know t.. using sessionAware..i need to know how to maintain the session in one form and different data's...u got my point?

Comment: Nope. You have the data in session; why do you need to continue to keep it in a form as well? In any case, you can use hidden fields. But no, I still don't understand the issue.

Comment: @MoorthyKS Do you want to know how to do it? You have different errors in JSP and with hibernate.

Comment: @MoorthyKS: Just store your data in some list and put that list into the session, and on every add get it from session add new element and put it back.

Answer (score 1):

When you submit your form data for the first time, place that form data in an Array and repeat the step as many times as you submit the new form.

Place the Array in session so that this Array will be preserved during repeating Form submission.

When you have finished with your Form submission part you can store the form data from the Array into a database.